# Template does not reflect when logged out in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a child theme and within that am overriding the Woocommerce plugin by copying appropriate files to my theme folder and editing them.

Example: in theme-name\woocommerce\content-product.php

...I edited the following line to show three products per row, instead of default 4

```
$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 3 );
```

I need to use this method instead for some particular purpose. Anyway, when I am logged in as Admin, Wordpress shows the layout in the new three products per row format, but when I log out or view in another browser, then it shows the default 4 and also does not consider some of the other css style changes I have done in my child theme.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? Do I need to publish somewhere or clear the cache or something?

Comment: only you can check these things ?

Comment: Yes, only when I am logged in as Admin, it reflects, doesn't reflect when logged out. I am assuming it is probably only showing the child template for logged in people. Not sure why.

Comment: Turns out wordpress had the Zen Cache plugin, I disabled it.

Comment: Caching issue? Empty the cache and try again without logging in.